# Distribute a XUL Application using Firefox binary

Tags: firefox, mpl

I'm going to release a XUL Application to my users. It is a freeware (and maybe it will be opensource-ed later). Previously I used to package it with XULRunner and ship them all to the end user. Now I have to use `firefox -app /path/to/application.ini` instead.

However, these slight modifications are required:

1. I'd like to remove all unnecessary files and directories. Including these directories: `browser, components, defaults, dictionaries, gmp-clearkey, icons, webapprt`, and almost all `.ini` files. This will save ~18Mb or so.
2. I want to rename `firefox`, `firefox.app` and `firefox.exe` to something else. Also, I want to change (or remove) the default firefox icon.
3. On Mac, there is an extra step. I'd like to remove 32-bit code from `XUL` library, [using `ditto` command](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050810112422666). This will save more than ~60Mb according to my tests. This is extremely usefull as I don't want to have both 32bit and 64bit on the same bundle.

Do these modifications require Mozilla's written permission?

There is some information on this page: [Mozilla Trademark Policy](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/foundation/trademarks/policy/). However, I can't make sure do they require written permission or don't.

Comment: If you read the section in the Mozilla Trademark Policy page entitled "Modifications," I think you will find that Mozilla's preference is that you turn off "branding mode."  In practice, I think that means you can modify the browser any way you see fit, provided you do not use the Mozilla branding in any way with the binary so modified, an arrangement that seems to satisfy both you and Mozilla.

Comment: Do you mean re-compiling the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer after contacting `trademarks AT Mozilla dot com`:

> If you are shipping a modified version of Firefox, **these steps are
>   required** :-) You may not brand it as Firefox in any way. As long as you
>   make that change, **you can make whatever other changes you want**. That's a freedom given to you by the open source licenses; you don't need our
>   permission.
>
> You will, of course, have to abide by the open source licenses governing
>   our code, for example by telling your users where to get the source code
>   of any MPLed code and Modifications. See:
>   https://www.mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/FAQ/